# Adding Javascript to ASP Dropdownlist on page load

Tags: javascript, asp.net, updatepanel, pageload

I'm working on an interactive web form that does not use an `UpdatePanel`, so I'm trying to use JavaScript to do most of the functionality. For this question, I'm trying to figure out how to get java script to add functions to a dropdownlist on PageLoad().

I have the following ASP file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Default.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            Discovery Form Templates
            <asp:DropDownList ID="uiFormTemplates" runat="server" DataTextField="Subject" DataValueField="DiscoveryFormID" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnChange="GetTemplateValue();">
                <asp:ListItem Text="--Select One--" Value=""/>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
        <div id="ChangePlate"></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And then this javascript:

```
function GetTemplateValue()
{
var dropdown = document.getElementById("uiFormTemplates");
var SelectedOption = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;

if (SelectedOption == null) {
    document.getElementById("ChangePlate").innerText = "There is nothing here.";
}
else {
    document.getElementById("ChangePlate").innerText = dropdown;
}
}
```

I'm trying to use the following javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#uiFormTemplates").onchange(function () { GetTemplateValue(); });
});
```

When I remove `OnChange="GetTemplateValue()"` from the `dropdownlist`, nothing happens, even with the second javascript method. Did I write my code wrong, or am I not even approaching this from the right angle? Either code critiques or some direction would be helpful right now, I'm a js noob.

Comment: As your control is asp.net control so the method which you are writing is server side method not client side code.

Comment: First off, check how the ID for that DDL is actually rendering. Most likely you need to change your javascript to look for `"<%= uiFormTemplates.ClientID %>"` instead of `"uiFormTemplates"`. ASP.NET normally changes the ID of tags with `runat=server` on them... so that is how you get the ID that is sent to the client.

Comment: @krshekhar could you clarify that, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're including jQuery (which you're using), there's no `onchange` method. You have to change it to `on('change', ...)`, or use the `change` method. Also, `#uiFormTemplates` shouldn't work, you have to use your control's `ClientID`

So:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#<%= uiFormTemplates.ClientID %>").on('change', function () { GetTemplateValue(); });
});
```

Or:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#<%= uiFormTemplates.ClientID %>").change(function () { GetTemplateValue(); });
});
```

Comment: Is that the `<%= uiFormTemplates.ClientID %>` mentioned above?

Comment: Okay, my method now reads `$('<%= uiFormTemplates.ClientID%>').change(function () { GetTemplateValue(); });` and it still isn't working. Is there an issue with the way that I chose the `clientID` or is that another issue?

Comment: That js code must be processed with asp to work. It seems you have it in an external file. Add it to `<script>` block on the `<head>` of your html.

Comment: I also realized that the references were not included in the head. Thanks!